# How can I pass current input value as an argument to bind in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I want to get input tag value in UserInput when I click button and change value of p tag in UserOutput.
I used this.state.input but is not working. It works when I use input change event instead of click.

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    input: 'initial'
  };

  setUserInputHandler = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      input: value
    });
    console.log('Value is', value);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <UserInput
          click={this.setUserInputHandler.bind(this, this.state.input)}
        />
        <UserOutput username={this.state.input} />
        <UserOutput username={this.state.input} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
const userInput = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className='UserInput'>
            <input
                type='text' />
            <button onClick={props.click}>Set</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
const userOutput = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{props.username}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get input field value on link click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080728/how-to-get-input-field-value-on-link-click)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of an input field using ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683770/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-input-field-using-reactjs)